# MS sharepoint mobile app for android - on-premise

Tags: app, mobile, android

Any updates on when we'll see on-premise support for the android mobile app? The IOS has had support for the past 10 months....

Answer (score 0):

The official channel (Sharepoint UserVoice) [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/540331-sharepoint-mobile-app-for-android/suggestions/16367923-please-allow-to-connect-with-sharepoint-2013-on-pr) still says that it is in works (no timeline as of now). I suggest you vote it up so that they know there is a demand for it.